# Having to call SetFocus twice in MS Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, setfocus, reentrancy

I found that for a couple of hours this code worked:

```
If KeyCode = 37 Then

    Me.Text12.SetFocus

End If
```

Then it mysteriously stopped working.  I thought it might have had something to do with processing the OnEnter subroutine (I move the cursor to the end of the text field).

However editing out the OnEnter subroutine didn't help.
The only other thing I'd done was change my input/keyboard language (to be able to type quote marks and have them appear immediately, huzzah!)

I now have this code:

```
On Error Resume Next

If KeyCode = 37 Then

    Me.Text12.SetFocus
    Me.Text12.SetFocus

End If
```

Which works.  So I know the 50+ pages of search results for SetFocus not working which relate to it being hidden, disabled, not visible, out for tea with the vicar etc do ***not*** apply here.

I've also tried setting the focus to another control first, and liberally applied DoEvents as well, neither of which helped.

Has anyone run into anything similar or is this just a really weird Heisenbug?

Comment: Oh yes, the error being thrown was Run Time Error 2110 - "Can't move the focus"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have something else going on. Set a **breakpoint** on the first `Me.Text12.SetFocus` and watch what happens when you step through the code (**F8**).

I suspect that you have another process being triggered that's cancelling the first `Me.Text12.SetFocus`.

Another possibility is your DB as corrupted. This is something Access is prone to do, especially with lots of edits to the forms and/or reports. Go to **File - Info**, then click on **Compact & Repair Database**.
It's not a bad idea to have Access do this automatically whenever you close it. Go to **File - Options - Current Database (tab)**, then check **Compact on Close**.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I discovered that it was sometimes branching to the click handler of the control which is losing focus.

And sometimes it isn't.  Hence Heisenbug.

I added a flag to tell the click handler to do nothing on that particular keystroke, and it seems to have solved the problem.

Before that I also tried your suggestion of compacting the database, but that didn't change the behaviour.